# Monotouch - ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib for unzip file

Tags: xamarin.ios, zip, sharpziplib

I'm using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib for unzip a file that contain file, folders and subfolders inside, but i'm getting an error that I didn't find here or in any other forum.

Code:

```
public static void UnZipFiles(string zipPathAndFile, string outputFolder, string password, bool deleteZipFile)
{
        ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(zipPathAndFile));
        if (password != null && password != String.Empty)
            s.Password = password;
        ZipEntry theEntry;
        string tmpEntry = String.Empty;
        while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            string directoryName = outputFolder;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);
            // create directory 
            if (directoryName != "")
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
            }
            if (fileName != String.Empty)
            {
                if (theEntry.Name.IndexOf(".ini") < 0)
                {
                    string fullPath = directoryName + "\\" + theEntry.Name;
                    fullPath = fullPath.Replace("\\ ", "\\");
                    string fullDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(fullDirPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(fullDirPath);
                    FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullPath);
                    int size = 2048;
                    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (size > 0)
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        s.Close();
        if (deleteZipFile)
        {
            File.Delete(zipPathAndFile);

        }
}
```

Error got:

```
Unhandled Exception: ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.SharpZipBaseException: Unknown block type 6
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Inflater.Decode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Inflater.Inflate (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.BodyRead (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.InitialRead (System.Byte[] destination, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.CloseEntry () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0Error connecting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:10001)

  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FolderNavigation.ZipController.UnZipFiles (System.String zipPathAndFile, System.String outputFolder, System.String password, Boolean deleteZipFile) [0x00119] in /Users/claudio/Projects/FolderNavigation/FolderNavigation/ZipController.cs:15 
  at FolderNavigation.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0005e] in /Users/claudio/Projects/FolderNavigation/FolderNavigation/Main.cs:43 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31 
  at FolderNavigation.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/claudio/Projects/FolderNavigation/FolderNavigation/Main.cs:14
```

Any idea?

Regards,
Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to unzip the file via the code on .NET in windows for example? Maybe the file is zipped by some technique SharpZipLib does not support?

I'm judging by the fact that error happens in 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Inflater.Decode' method, which if you check the source code for the SharpZipLib just decodes the array of deflated bytes.

Comment: Yes man, it's right. I figured out that the error is when I'm  download this zip file. When I tried with a local zip file, it worked fine.